# Salt Jinja Syntax error: no filter named 'yaml_encode'

Tags: yaml, salt-stack, jinja2

When running `salt '*' state.highstate`, my SLS files fail to render with the following message:

```
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:files' failed: Jinja syntax error: no filter named 'yaml_encode'; line 6

---
{% for folder, options in salt['pillar.get']('dirs', {}).items() %}
{{ folder }}:
{%- load_yaml as foo %}
  file.directory:
    {% for key, val in options.items() %}
    - {{ key }}: {{ val|yaml_encode }}    <======================
    {% endfor %}
    - order: 1
{%- endload %}
{% endfor %}
---
```

[The docs](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html#filters) show this filter just being used wherever you want to escape YAML so I don't know why the filter is not defined.

All minions and the master are running Ubuntu Server 14.04, and Salt 2014.7.1 from the [Launchpad PPA](https://launchpad.net/~saltstack/+archive/ubuntu/salt)

Comment: Which version of salt your are using? You can get it by running `salt --versions`   
IIRC, `yaml_encode` only available in salt 2014.7.0+

Comment: 2014.7.1 for all masters and minions. (sorry, I will edit the question to include that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the filter is documented, it is misleading as the docs are generated from the current develop branch, not the latest stable branch.

[The docs for older versions are available from readthedocs.org.](http://salt.readthedocs.org/en/v2014.7.0/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.jinja.html#filters)

[The pull request that introduced this feature](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/17290) did not yet get "merged back" into 2014.7.